# Present participle with Simple Present tense

Tags: word-usage, participles

1. The boy comes running.
2. My father stands behind me smiling. (I saw the first example in a grammar book and the second in a prose)

In which cases is this particular form (S + action-verb + s/es of the verb + 'ing' form of the another action-verb) applicable?

Comment: Note that one answer at the duplicate offers four possible structures for [verb + _ing_-form] (where the '+' may merely mean 'followed by').

Answer (score 1):

Present participles can behave as adverbs. See [this webpage](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/2921000293).

The word *running* here is an adverb, saying how the boy comes. Similarly, the word *smiling* describes how the father stands.

Comment: I'd agree with the adverbial classification if it were 'The boy comes, running'. But 'The boy comes running [with us] could well be the phase structure where 'comes running' (cf go fishing / go shopping) is a complex verb phrase.

Comment: @Edwin: Two different meanings, and "the boy comes running" (no comma) could be either one.

Comment: Hence the 'could well be'.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the matter simple, V+ ing is called present participle form of verb. For our ease we would call them ing-verbs. They may be part of a verb phrase in tensed conjugation (continuous/ prefect continuous) in all the three tenses, present, past, future.

- Please remember the word, 'present participle' is misleading. It has nothing to do with present alone.
- You missed one aspect. Ing-verbs can function as noun.
- Ing-verbs  can function as  adjectives atttributively or predictively. While qualifying they can sometimes imbibe an 'action- in- progress-concept', but not always. When they modify they behave like adverbs answering 'how' or 'in what manner'.
- Such -ing verbs, when not used in tensed conjugation, acquire the nominal or adjectival/ adverbial  properties.

Running—  not in tensed conjugation, explains manner modifying verb : an adverb.

Smiling— not part of verb. (Present participle). He was ( in the state of) smiling. It is an adverb.

Smiling is a good gesture. It is a noun here.

Statue of laughing Buddha./ Stutue of Buddha laughing (adjective)

If my memory doesn't fail me, you asked a similar question on this site. I think we are clear now.